# Train sklearn tree with strings

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can I train sklearn with strings. So when i input string to prediction it predicts currently when I am trying to add a string to DecisionTreeClassifier.predict it says that it cannot be converted to float.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. But I guess you want to do some classification. Am I right ?

Comment: Please add more specifics to your question, e.g. with example data, because answers will depend on whether you mean simply categorical data or actual text.

Answer (score 0):

One way to train a machine learning classifier on natural language is to use the **Bag of Words** technique. Sklearn has the [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) function to preform tokenization.

From the documentation:

> In order to address this, scikit-learn provides utilities for the most common ways to extract numerical features from text content, namely:
>
> - Tokenizing strings and giving an integer id for each possible token, for instance by using white-spaces and punctuation as token separators.
>
>   - Counting the occurrences of tokens in each document.
>       normalizing and weighting with diminishing importance tokens that occur in the majority of samples / documents.
>   - Features and samples are defined as follows:
>   - Each individual token occurrence frequency (normalized or not) is treated as a feature. The vector of all the token frequencies for a given document is considered a multivariate sample.